# Plotting factors in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to produce the below plot into R.

[image: Plot in Excel to be reproduced in R]

My coding is this so far:

```
maraqa <- c(84.8,68.9,84.9,92.5)
aqua <- c(75,65.1,79.4,82.3)
mar <- c(84.7,68.3,84.5,77.4)

x <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

Now what? Thanks!

Comment: Here's the dropbox link if you cannot see the plot(I can't): [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52102974/plot2.png)

Comment: Please read one of the many introductions and tutorials that are available on the net. We expect you to spend some minimal effort before you ask a question here.

Comment: I have looked, I would be grateful to be pointed in the right direction

Comment: Start with `?plot` and `?lines`...and then come back to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution... but look at the help pages to find out which parameters controls[image] what...

```
maraqa <- c(84.8,68.9,84.9,92.5)
aqua <- c(75,65.1,79.4,82.3)
mar <- c(84.7,68.3,84.5,77.4)

# combine data as matrix
mat<-cbind(maraqa, aqua, mar)
rownames(mat)<-c("A", "B", "C", "D")

#define colours
coll<-c("red", "blue", "black")

matplot(mat, type="l", ylim=c(60, 95), ylab="y TBA", main="TBA", xlab="x TBA", 
        axes=FALSE, frame.plot=FALSE, col=coll, lty=rep(1,3))
# axes= do you want standart axis or make your own?
# frame.plot= frame arround plot yes/no

matpoints(mat, pch=rep(17,3), col=coll, ad=TRUE)
# to add points, pch controlls for type of points

axis(side=1, 1:4, labels=rownames(mat))
axis(side=2, 60:95, labels=60:95)
legend("topleft",# position
       legend=c("maraqa", "aqua", "mar"),# names in legend,
       lty=c(1,1,1),# type of filling in this case solide line,
       col = coll,# colour of filling, 
       cex=0.7)# scaling parameter
```

Comment: if you also like a grid use -> `grid`

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this, it wasn't so obvious to me what to do!

Comment: You may also find this tutorial useful: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/